# How to give importance to recent data in a large dataset

Tags: machine-learning, classification, time-series, data

I am solving a binary classification problem which is also partly a time-series problem. This means that the recent data is more relevant than the old data. But how can I assign more importance to the recent data as compared to the old one?

Answer (score 1):

Time-series methods like LSTM, Kalman filters and Markov models handle this automatically. So, assigning more importance to more recent data is in their structure.